# Reading blank cell Apache POI 3.17

Tags: java, excel, null, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI 3.17 to read some excel data. My second column (index of 1 because of 0 index) is empty and I want to be able to read it, but can't get my code to read the cell as empty. I have this which isn't working:

```
Cell c = row.getCell(1, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // do whatever
 }
```

But the second parameter can't be taken in. I get "RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: I remember I had the whole helper method to detect blank cells.

Answer (score 2):

The constants in the `Row` class itself were deprecated as of POI-3.15-beta2, marked for removal as of POI-3.17.  [This diff](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.java?r1=1717162&r2=1750172') shows when those constants were deprecated in June 2016.  They were removed in 3.17.

Before 3.17, the enum [`Row.MissingCellPolicy`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.MissingCellPolicy.html) was already defined as a replacement.  If you're using 3.17, then you must use that enum; it is defined as a member of the `Row` interface.  Try

```
Cell c = row.getCell(1, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
```